# How to use generics for the same method with different input

Tags: java

```
private Set<String> extractOfferKeysForAbstractOffers(List<AbstractOfferDto> selectedOffers) {
        Set<String> offerKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        for (AbstractOfferDto offer : selectedOffers) {
            offerKeys.add(offer.getOfferKey());
        }
        return offerKeys;
    }

 private Set<String> extractOfferKeysForOffers(List<OfferDto> selectedOffers) {
        Set<String> offerKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        for (OfferDto offer : selectedOffers) {
            offerKeys.add(offer.getOfferKey());
        }
        return offerKeys;
    }
```

Instead of using almost the same method just input is different I want to use generics. I create it like this.

```
private <T> Set<String> extractOfferKeysForOffers(List<T> offers) {
        Set<String> offerKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        for (T offer : offers) {
            offerKeys.add(offer.getOfferKey());
        }
        return offerKeys;
    }
```

but problem is that `offer.getOfferKey()` is not recognized. Only options for offer are `AbstractOfferDto` or `OfferDto`.

How can I use generics for this example?

Comment: Use `T extends CommonInterface`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
  public interface IOffer {
     String getOfferKey();
  }

  public class OfferDto implements IOffer { ... }

  public class AbstractOfferDto implements IOffer { ... }

  class X {    
    private <T extends IOffer> Set<String> extractOfferKeysForOffers(List<T> offers) {
        Set<String> offerKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        for (T offer : offers) {
            offerKeys.add(offer.getOfferKey());
        }
        return offerKeys;
    }
  }
```

The above is a general solution. If `OfferDto` extends `AbstractOfferDto`, the extra interface is not needed:

```
  class X {    
    private <T extends AbstractOfferDto> Set<String> extractOfferKeysForOffers(List<T> offers) {
        Set<String> offerKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        for (T offer : offers) {
            offerKeys.add(offer.getOfferKey());
        }
        return offerKeys;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

Tell the compiler about the abstract type:

```
private <T extends AbstractOfferDto> Set<String> extractOfferKeysForOffers(List<T> offers) {
        Set<String> offerKeys = new HashSet<String>();
        for (T offer : offers) {
            offerKeys.add(offer.getOfferKey());
        }
        return offerKeys;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for idea but Offer is not extended of abstract class.